# SendBird group channel permission of session token

Tags: sendbird

Is it possible to disable write access to group channels using session token? That is, users with session token can still read/send messages in existing group channels but can't create new channels or invite new members. New group channels can only be created and modified by platform api with api token.

In my use case, I don't allow users to create groups or invite members directly by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of session tokens is for user authentication, not roles and permissions. More information about session tokens can be found [here](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform/user#3_create_a_user).

You can, however, use the user metadata to store a role. You can then enforce your own permissions at the client UI level (won't be restricted by the SDK or SendBird itself). Alternatively, you can make a call to your application's own server, authorize the request based on the user's role, and then make a platform API request if the user is authorized to perform that action. More information about user metadata can be found [here](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform/user_metadata#2_user_metadata).

Additionally, some channel activities can be managed by assigning a user as a channel operator. This allows the user to perform channel moderation actions such as banning or muting other channel members. More information on that can be found [here](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript/user_type#3_operator).